# laravel passport:client --personal 'access_token_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I've installed Laravel Passport (with `php artisan passport:install --uuids`) and try to generate a PAT. Before this can be done a personal client must be created.

Whenever I run:

```bash
php artisan passport:client --personal
```

a new client will be created to my database, but I get the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'access_token_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `oauth_refresh_tokens` (`client_id`) values (96cf1614-fe2e-42fa-83ba-ac804943c84b))

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:759
    755▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    756▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    757▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    758▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 759▕             throw new QueryException(
    760▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    761▕             );
    762▕         }
    763▕     }

      +28 vendor frames 
  29  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I could fix this by `nullable`ing the blamed field, I'm just wondering if anyone else had the same issue with passport's PAT..

This is the original migration:

```php
public function up()                                                           
{                                                                              
    $this->schema->create('oauth_refresh_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id', 100)->primary();                                  
        $table->string('access_token_id', 100)->index();                       
        $table->boolean('revoked');                                            
        $table->dateTime('expires_at')->nullable();                            
    });                                                                        
}
```

And this update was needed to get it working:

```php
public function up()
{
    $this->schema->create('oauth_refresh_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->uuid('client_id')->nullable()->index();
        $table->uuid('access_token_id')->nullable()->index();
        $table->boolean('revoked')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('expires_at')->nullable();
    });
}
```

#### Update

After implementing the above workaround, I run

```
php artisan passport:client --personal --user_id=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 --name=PAT
```

..but the `user_id` is also not associated in the `oauth_clients_table`:

| id | user_id | name | secret | provider | redirect | personal_access_client | password_client | revoked | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 96cf9c98-97fa-494d-8f13-01a5856dbe3b | `NULL` | PAT | $2y$... | NULL | http://localhost | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2022-07-18 22:44:56.0 | 2022-07-18 22:44:56.0 |

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your database then use this command

```
php artisan passport:install
```

I had same problem and this saved me!

Comment: nop, as mentioned above, passport is installed.